# Blocking Outbound Internet connection on Azure VM but keeping Antimalware Extension working

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have a VM on which I blocked outbound connectivity to the Internet using a NetworkSecurityGroup.

I installed the Antimalware Extension and realized that the installation would not work without connecting to the Internet. So I removed the NetworkSecurityGroup to reactivate outbound connectivity and everything installed correctly.

Now I want put the NetworkSecurityGroup restrictions back (No internet access).

What exclusions should I add to the NetworkSecurityGroup so that the Antimalware Extension continue working and update normally?

Comment: That depends on the Antimalware software. I would not think that there's some special antimalware software for Azure but some standard software from someone. So, if you know the product look at manufacture's documentation.

Comment: It is Microsoft Antimalware solution.